# ViewControllers and :(id) senders

Tags: uiviewcontroller

I want to make a class on my project for changing views. This is how I would usualy do it:

```
NewViewController * newView = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self presentModalViewController:newView animated:NO];
```

I would like to send the NewViewController instance to another classes method so I can put the rest of the view changing code in there allowing for less clutter in my main class files. How would I go about doing this?

Would it be something like:

```
-(void) switchViews:(UIViewController *) switchTo{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you make new viewController by modal, it allocates memory each other

In this case, Delegate is the best way you can do it easily.

"Delegate" means a protocol of classes. so have to practice it.